# Fallback fonts in react native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Are there any current solutions for fallback fonts in `react-native`?

I have a font used throughout my application, but a specific character is not supported by this font. I would like it to fallback to a custom font (specifically for iOS) since it looks like the styling for this character changed from iOS 12 to iOS 13.

I see in the react native `Text` [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text) that multiple fonts are not supported, but I'm wondering if there are any third party solutions for this.

EDIT: The font cannot be hard coded since this character may show up in any string. It must fall back at a high level text component used throughout the application.

Cheers!

Comment: Have this exact issue. Would be nice if it got solved / anyone had an solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there is no way that React Native will automatically do that. You have to define your special character and tell RN to use your alternative fonts. There is a RN library to do that for you: [React Native Hightlight Words](https://github.com/clauderic/react-native-highlight-words). This component will detect your special character, and render it with your custom style (including your font)

Comment: sorry, I should have clarified that the special character cannot be wrapped in a specific Text component since it may show up in any string. Updated the question, hopefully thats more clear

Comment: I'd prefer a native solution. Since we could render an unbounded amount of text and this package seems to map over text on every render on the JS thread

Comment: @TaylorJohnson How did you solve this in the end? Since you only need one or a few missing characters it might be possible to use font tools to copy the missing glyph into the font file that you embed in the app? (so long as you've got the right licenses for both fonts of course)

Comment: unfortunately i think we used custom glyphs as a work around